# Complete Kähler Metrics

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I read the Complex Analytic and Algebraic Geometry, which says that a weakly pseudoconvex Kähler manifolds $(M,\omega)$, in the sense that it admits a smooth plurisubharmonic exhaustive function $\psi$,  carries a complete Kähler metric $\hat{\omega}.$

The author construct $$\hat{\omega}:=\omega+i\partial\bar\partial(\psi)^2$$ and by $$\hat{\omega}=\omega+2i\psi\partial\bar\partial\psi+2i\partial\psi\wedge\bar\partial\psi\ge 2i\partial\psi\wedge\bar\partial\psi$$
to show that $|d\psi|_{\hat{\omega}}\le 1$ concluding $(M,\hat{\omega})$ is complete by the lemma before this content.

My problem is that why not just consider $\hat{\omega}:=i\partial\bar\partial(\psi)^2?$ This is a metric and still implies the inequality above. Does this mean that the Kähler condition at first can be omitted?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I think it’s because $/psi$ is just assumed to be plurisubharmonic, not _strictly plurisubharmonic_. This means $i/partial/bar/partial /psi $ is only positive semidefinite.

Comment: That may be the point... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assume $ϕ$ is the strictly plurisubharmonic exhaustion function for a Stein
manifold $M$. Without loss of generality, we can assume $ϕ ≥ 0$. (Otherwise
consider $\exp ϕ$ instead of $ϕ$. ) then $∂\bar ∂ϕ^2$ gives a complete Kahler metric on $M$. See this [lecture note for details](http://ir.nul.nagoya-u.ac.jp/jspui/bitstream/2237/23013/1/k11135_thesis.pdf) and [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.06451.pdf) .

See also [Lemma 1.4.2](https://edoc.hu-berlin.de/bitstream/handle/18452/15386/Brinkschulte.pdf?sequence=1)

Comment: It would be helpful if you conveyed at least a few of the details of the linked documents.

Comment: See my comments here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239677/does-a-kähler-manifold-always-admit-a-complete-kähler-metric/271277#271277