# Metric on the complement of a divisor is complete?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $\bar{M}$ be a projective manifold, $D$ a smooth ample divisor with normal crossings, and $S$ a defining section of $D$. It is claimed that the metric on $\bar{M} \setminus D$ corresponding to the Kähler form $$\frac{i}{2\pi} \partial \bar{\partial} (-\text{log}\Vert S \Vert^2)^{\frac{n+1}{n}}$$ is complete. How does one see this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2526052/complete-k%C3%A4hler-metrics?rq=1

Comment: Excellent, thanks!

Comment: The better reference is https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239677/does-a-k%C3%A4hler-manifold-always-admit-a-complete-k%C3%A4hler-metric/271277#271277